# Hindi Characters not displaying in ms word document

Tags: utf-8, ms-word, hindi

I have generated a word document (docx) on fly, which contains 2 languages: English and Hindi.

English characters are displayed correctly but Hindi characters are displayed as box [] when you open the document. However when you select the hindi text (box) and re select the font from drop down to Aerial the characters displays.

Well the full document already has Aerial font but for some reason it doesn't display hindi characters when you open it.

I have tried to google for the it but I didn't found any instruction which may solve this issue. Please can anyone advise what is going on here.

Comment: Please show us the code that writes content in the two languages to the document. Right off-hand I'd say your problem may come from not applying the correct language formatting to the Hindi text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that there is no way to do it. Alternatively, I have changed the font to "Mangal" and it works fine.
Thanks all!

Comment: Mangal supports Devanagari, whereas Arial does not. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/arial-unicode-ms

Answer (score 0):

Even I had same issue but it looks like MS WORD has got the solution.
in MS WORD 2007

step 1 - Go to '*Review*'

Step 2 - Click on '*Set Language'*

Step 3- Select check box '*Detect Language automatically*'

Close word file and reopen it :)
Hope it help

Answer (score -1):

try installing Kruti Dev 010 font. It worked for me.